# Is it possible to display nicknames in the contact list?

Tags: contacts, 2.3-gingerbread, phone-app, samsung-touchwiz

Is it possible to use nicknames, instead of first+last names, as the contact's display name in the contact list and/or the incoming/outgoing call view?

Device is Samsung Galaxy S 2.

Edit: to be clear, I wouldn't mind installing an alternative contacts app, if there's no other way to do this with the default one.

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: @Matthew Samsung Galaxy S 2. Didn't think that it mattered, but if it does please add it as a tag (I can't, rep's too low).

Comment: More important is that the S2 has TouchWiz, which has a modified Contacts app.

Comment: With my Samsung Galaxy 5 I can add an _alias_ to a contact, and it will be shown in the list with that nickname as long as it has no first nor last name... I'm afraid it's not a good solution...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with the default app for contacts. Try [Go Contacts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jbapps.contact&feature=search_result) which is a rich app on displaying contacts.

Although the feature you are looking for is available on the default contact display of the [MIUI ROM](http://miuiandroid.com/). If you have rooted your phone, consider installing MIUI.

Comment: I've tried Go Contacts but saw no option there to display nicknames...

Comment: The link to Go Contacts is broken. It appears that the app is been discontinued.

Comment: @PhoneixS Makes sense, this post is 12 years old!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I decided to include nicknames in FirstName field, in format like this (without square brackets):

```
[Firstname] ([Nickname]) [Lastname]
```

With [Go Contacts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jbapps.contact) installed (it's free) you can find a contact by any match of firstname, lastname or nickname.

Comment: Actually the TouchWiz contacts application already allows me to find contacts by nickname, it just doesn't display it, which is the problem.

Comment: I know, but this advice is primarily about contact naming, and 'Go Contacts' - is just an example of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DW Contacts & Phone Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dw.contacts.free), it allows displaying by Nickname, however SMS app will still display full name.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how? I was able to sort by nickname, but was not able to see it in the list...

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can create a program for that. This is a very hacky approach - Use ContentProvider to swap first+last names with nick names. In that manner you won't lose anything.